# A question about Riesz - Fischer theorem's proof

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In Riesz-Fischer theorem's proof, when we put
$$
 g_k =|f_{n_1}|+|f_{n_2}-f_{n_1}|+ \cdots + |f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k-1}}|
$$
it is easy to get (by Minkowski's inequality)
$$
 \left \| g_k \right \|_p \leq \left\|f_{n_1}\right\|_p+\left\|f_{n_2}-f_{n_1}\right\|_p+ \cdots + \left\|f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k-1}}\right\|_p.
$$

Can you show  me how to formally pass to the limit in order to obtain

$$
\left \| g \right \|_p \leq  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \| f_{n_k}-f_{n_{k-1}} \right \|_p
$$

? Thanks

Comment: Monotone convergence. You have $\lVert g_k\rVert_p \leqslant \sum \lVert f_{n_m} - f_{n_{m-1}}\rVert$, and $\lvert g_k\rvert^p \uparrow \lvert g\rvert^p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for all $k$ we have

$$\lVert g_k\rVert_p \leqslant \sum_{m=1}^\infty \lVert f_{n_m} - f_{n_{m-1}}\rVert_p$$

(with $f_{n_0} = 0$), and $\lvert g_k\rvert^p \uparrow \lvert g\rvert^p$ monotonically, the monotone convergence theorem tells us

$$\lVert g\rVert_p \leqslant \sum_{m=1}^\infty \lVert f_{n_m} - f_{n_{m-1}}\rVert_p.$$

Comment: How fitting that a question about Fischer's theorem, someone named Fischer posts an answer. Are you the same Fischer from the title of the question?

Comment: I'm old, but I'm not _that_ old. Not even the same family :(

Comment: Well, it won't be the first time people who've been dead for nearly 60 years are using the internet... I mean, evidence shows that a lot of people whose brain capacity is no larger than that of homo erectus are using the internet. These folks should have been extinct (in the numbers which appear online) some two hundred thousand years ago...

Comment: @DanielFischer: sorry for the silly question, but I was reading Rudin's book and there was a passage in which Fatou's lemma apparently had to be used. However I prefer this monotone convergence argument. Thanks again.

Comment: One can use either. I find the monotone convergence theorem more natural here.